# I need to count how many .zip files in a folder and transfer to a variable. Then compare with successful 226 transfers in a txt log file

Tags: variables, ftp, batch-file

I found this site using a search which was a great help.  I was able to modify part of a previous solution to do what I need but I still need some help.  I need to do this in a batch file and was hoping to get a solution or two.

What I need to do is Transfer 1 to 10 zip files from my PC to multiple FTP Servers.  I then need to check to make sure they are transferred successfully.  On my PC I'm using regular MS FTP and the servers are using IndiFTPD.  I have everything done except for the checking part.  Some of the FTP Servers are Dial up and wireless and they get disconnected from time to time.  So if I'm transferring say 3 files and the first one fails but the other two are successful my script lists it as successful.

I have was able to get a count of how many zip files are in the transfer folder and put it into a variable.  The code for that is:

```
@echo off


for /f %%A in ('dir *.zip ^| find "File(s)"') do set cnt=%%A
echo Zip File count = %cnt%
```

What I'm having trouble with is getting the same information from the text log file of the FTP transfer and then comparing the two to make sure they are the same.  Here is an example of a log of an FTP transfer I would make:

```
ftp> Connected to Host1.
open Host1 21 
220 Connected to IndiFTPD
ftp> Username user 
user1
331 Password required for Folder1.

230 User user1 logged in.
ftp> Hash mark printing On  ftp: (2048 bytes/hash mark) .
ftp> hash 
binary 
200 Type is set to I.
ftp> mput *.zip 
200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2012_07_01_03_40_1_3_TESTFTPs.zip.
###############################################################################################
226 [Bytes: 195046][Time: 1.13 s][Speed: 168.26 K/s]
ftp: 195046 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
0.78251.67200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2012_07_01_03_40_2_3_TESTFTPs.zip.
###############################################################################################
226 [Bytes: 195046][Time: 1.13 s][Speed: 168.41 K/s]
ftp: 195046 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
0.77253.31200 PORT command successful.
150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for 2012_07_01_03_40_3_3_TESTFTPs.zip.
###############################################################################################
226 [Bytes: 195046][Time: 1.14 s][Speed: 166.79 K/s]
ftp: 195046 bytes sent in Seconds Kbytes/sec.
ftp> 0.78249.42bye 
221 Exit.
```

I would like to be able to use the `%cnt%` variable from the first part of the script to get the count of zip files I have.  Then I would like to get able to count the number of "226 [Bytes" in the log file which is named terminal-ftp.txt.  Then once I have both values in variable form I need to compare them to ensure I have 3 FTP files and 3 Successful 226 transfers.  If they don't match then I would need to flag it up for a retry.

Answer (score 1):

Get the 226 results:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=3 delims=: " %%A in (`find /c "226 [Bytes" "terminal-ftp.txt"`) do set "xTTS=%%A"
echo Successful 226 Transfers = %xTTS%
```

Compare the results:

```
if "%xTTS%" EQU "%cnt%" echo The counts match
if "%xTTS%" NEQ "%cnt%" echo The counts do not match
```

For great Batch references:

`command /?`, [`Technet`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772390%28v=ws.10%29.aspx), [`Rob van de Woude`](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/batchfiles.php), [`DosTips`](http://www.dostips.com/), and [`SS64`](http://ss64.com/)

Comment: +1 - good answer, but one minor comment. I've never understood why many people use `"usebackq"` when it is not needed. The option can be removed and regular single quotes used in the IN() clause instead of the backquotes. The only time I've ever used the '"usebackq"` option is when reading from a file when the name must be quoted.

Comment: @dbenham  Thanks, and I tend to use the `usebackq` option just because I like it better.  I like that all the options are surrounded by a form of quotations, I like that filenameset always works (not just when it does not contain spaces), and I like using a single for loop style in my code as to reduce confusion (only have to remember 3 for loop types instead of 6).  So it is not out of necessity, but out of personal opinion that it is better. :)

Comment: Well thought out response. I started to go down that same road, but reading from a string prevented me from always using `"usebackq"`. I almost always want my strings to be quoted so that I don't have to worry about escaping special characters. Plus I don't like unnecessary typing :) So my style is to generally use `"usebackq"` when reading from a file, and "never" use it for strings or commands. I know that contradicts my first poorly worded comment. I really should have said "the only time I find the option necessary is..." not "the only time I use it is ...". Cheers :)